# possible? Typedef enum in C without members, add members in another file

Tags: c, enums, typedef, preprocessor

**Problem**

For a library im writing the user has to define different input values, as in

```
enum {
    A_VALUE1,
    A_VALUE2
};
enum {
    B_VALUE1,
    B_VALUE2
};
```

These values can then be used as params for library functions, e.g.:

```
library_function( context_handle_1, A_VALUE1 );
library_function( context_handle_2, B_VALUE1 );
```

What i would like to do is:

- `typedef` the `enum` (more clear, better readability, compiler warnings) but
- have dont want multiple implementations of `library_function` and therefore just one type for the enum, while
- the library user creates the actual values for the enums and can use
- multiple enums for different library instances.

---

**Tried A**

```
typedef enum my_enum_type;

my_enum_type {
   IDENTIFIER_SET_A
}

my_enum_type {
   IDENTIFIER_SET_B
}
```

> error: must use 'enum' tag to refer to type 'my_type'.

---

**Tried B**

Use preprocessor macros to create a unique variable type for each enum:

```
#define MY_ENUM(name, ...) \
typedef enum name##_enum_type {
    __VA_ARGS__,
    name##_COUNT
};
```

This will require a separate library function for each `name` or a type conversion on a function call. The additional name##_COUNT could come in handy, but then i need to know `name` to access it.

---

**Tried C**

Using preprocessor macros to create multiple datatypes, then wrap the function call in a `#define` to typecast it back, like

```
#define VALUES(...) typedef enum __FILE__##__LINE__## { __VA_ARGS__ } __FILE__##__LINE__##_t
#define lib_run(func, value) func((my_enum_type)value)

typedef int my_enum_type;

func(my_enum_type value) {
   do_something();
}
```

I tried using something like `__FILE__` or `__LINE__` to create an automated name that is both unique and does not need to be given by the user. But the qoutes in `__FILE__` kill this approach, as it generates invalid variable names.

---

**Question**

What could be a valid way to

- create an enum type with typedef for a library
- do not add any identifiers to this type yet, but
- allow a library user to create enums with identifiers using this type
- pass any value of these enum to the same function (bonus: without type conversion)

---

---

Comment: I'm probably tired, but I can't get everything, forgive me, Could you explain to me the reason why a single enum with all the identifiers is forbidden? Or you aready have two enums, you cannot modify them and you would like to merge them?

Comment: Another question is: who is "the library user"? Another developer? Have they to fill a configuration header file with those enums?

Comment: I don't understand your use case. If those values have a specific meaning in your library, what's the point of letting the user choose their own names? On the other hand, if they are irrelevant to your library, why don't you just use an integer instead (after all, the user can still pass an enum if they desire)?

Comment: in this case its for a state machine lilbrary, so the enums could be states or events and are application specific, so i cannot hardcode them into the library. The user is a developer using the library.

As I want to allow using multiple instances of the machine in parallel (each with their own states and events) I am not looking to merge the enums.

I guess i could really just use an int (what is actually what im doing so far, but i thought there might be a .. different way).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a forward declaration of the type using

```
enum tag_name;
```

then create a `typedef` using this *incomplete* definition with

```
typedef enum tag_name my_enum_type;
```

and expose those in a header file, and then complete the definition in a .c file using

```
enum tag_name { ... };
```

What you *cannot* do is define the type as

```
enum tag_name { ENUM1, ENUM2 };
```

and then later on add

```
enum tag_name { ENUM3 };
```

The type is *complete* after the closing `}` of the first definition - you can't add any more enumeration constants after that point.  C just doesn't work like that.

I'm not fond of using `typedef` *just* to create a new name - the user of the type still needs to know it's an `enum` type (or at least that it's an integral value).  The abstraction is "leaky" and just adds clutter.  Either create a *complete* abstraction where the user of the type does not have to be aware of how it's implemented, or don't use an abstraction at all.

Answer (score 1):

`enum`s are for readability and for the compiler.

An easy way is for the header file for the library to contain the `enum` definition (the code calling the library also needs to know the `enum` definition.)

By having the `enum` definition in the header file (note, not an instance of the `enum`, just the definition.)  any file that includes that header file can access the library function and pass valid `enum` parameters

Strongly suggest to NOT turn that `enum` definition into a `typedef` name

Do notice the difference between a `enum` definition and an instance of that `enum`

Instance:

```
enum myEnum enumInstance;
```

Definition:

```
enum myEnum { ... };
```

Anonymous:

```
enum { ... };
```

All where the `...` is the list of name=value pairs. separated by commas.

for flexibility, do NOT combine the definition with an instance, I.E.

```
enum myEnum { ... } enumInstance;
```

or

```
enum { ... } enumInstance;
```